# Automated way to show up to a certain number of decimal points depending on value of number

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am dealing with generating reports with values that are sometimes integral, sometimes 1 decimal and sometimes 2 decimals. I would like to find a way to display these numbers with as few decimal points as possible. So 1 would always be 1 and not 1.0 or 1.00 whereas 2.5743 would be 2.57. Is there a way to automatically doing this slash something helpful in an iOS SDK that takes care of this?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't some "remove all trailing zeros" property that you can use.  I would suggest using `NSRange` and the `NSString .length` property with a couple if statements to check if the last digit is "0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `NSNumberFormatter` with `maximumFractionDigits` set to 2.

```
@import Foundation;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(1)]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(1.0)]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(2.5743)]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(2.5)]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(2.7)]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(2.699)]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(2.71001)]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2016-02-04 13:46:36.002 commandLine[27474:1266926] 1
2016-02-04 13:46:36.002 commandLine[27474:1266926] 1
2016-02-04 13:46:36.003 commandLine[27474:1266926] 2.57
2016-02-04 13:46:36.003 commandLine[27474:1266926] 2.5
2016-02-04 13:46:36.003 commandLine[27474:1266926] 2.7
2016-02-04 13:46:36.003 commandLine[27474:1266926] 2.7
2016-02-04 13:46:36.003 commandLine[27474:1266926] 2.71
```